# jQuery Function issue?

Tags: jquery, function

```
function loadData(strFileURL, strFormQuery, elmLoadTo, fncNextAction) {
  $(elmLoadTo).load(strFileURL, strFormQuery, function(response, status) {
    if (status == "success") {
      if($(this).find(":input").is("select")) {
        $(this).change(function() {
          fncNextAction();
        });
      }
    fncNextAction(); //----offending entry--
  } else {
    alertMsg(elmLoadTo);
  }
});
```

I am getting message in both Chrome and Firefox:

> Uncaught TypeError: fncNextFunction is not a function

for the third (before else) location?? But it works as intended. Which is to just call the next function which call another function in a series of form select/text inputs in jQuery search page! 
I feel the issue could be something with namespaces. The function definition is in the global space (not sure my lingo is correct) but the search forms are in different/various namespaces loaded when needed? And keep calling the same function.

Comment: You're assigning an event (to the `selects`) that calls a function that isn't in scope since it's being used (and passed) as a callback, would be my first guess (in the `change` event handler).

Comment: so do you pass a function as that argument???

Comment: could you post more of your JS please?

Comment: Yes, this is what I am trying to do. If the query returns only one database record the  new element is a text input and we move down the tree. If there a more than one record the new element is a select input with a default empty option, a change event is attached to it and again down the tree. Basically when get to the bottom of all inputs there will be a bunch of empty selects or read only text inputs.

Comment: the "uncaught error" is pointing to the `fncNextAction()` inside the `if` statement` but before the `else`?

Comment: And here a function from D namespace that calls the global function which is generating the error message:loadSystems : function() {
  loadData('../DV/Search.asp', null, '#systems', D.loadItems);
 }

Comment: var FIREPLAN = {
 loadFacilities : function() {
 
  loadData('../FSP/FspFacilities.asp', $('#frmSearch').serialize(),'#facilities', FIREPLAN.loadFirePlan);
 
 },
 loadFirePlan : function() {
  ....blah, blah .....
 }
};